# How to read the value of an observable in angular 5 to display or hide error message

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an observable variable declared in my search component

```
totalProducts$ = Observable<number>;  (this is based on its declaration in store).
```

Now I set this variable from store as follows:

```
this.totalResults$ = this.store.select(reducers.getTotalProducts);
```

I am then trying to display error message in my html template using `ngIf`.
I want to check the value of totalProducts and accordingly change the error message. how do I do that?
so I have:

```
<div class="search-msg" *ngIf="(formSubmitAttempt) && totalResults$>0"> <br> <br> {{(totalResults$ | async)}} Results found </div>

<ng-template #noResults> <br> <br>
  <div class="search-msg">
    We did not Find any results for {{searchTerm}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Is that way how we can compare `totalResults$`?

How do I achieve this?

Comment: is your ngIf working?

Comment: What is the type contained within the observable? If it's an array, you may need to use .length

Comment: Can you print out the `totalResults` on the template? `{{totalResults}}`

Comment: ngIf is working but without totalResults$, which is a number. Its printing totalResults$ only when it is non zero. Otherwise it just prints "      Results found"

Answer (score 1):

To get value of observable you can:

```
(totalResults$ | async) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an array you may need to add .length.
As it’s an Observable you could try the following:

```
 *ngIf="(formSubmitAttempt) && (totalResults$ | async).length > 0">
```